# How to add separator to layout

Tags: layout, gtk, separator

I want to add `vseparator` to layout in GTK 2.0.

It's like the toolbar.

Here's part of code:

```
GtkWidget *layout, vsparator;
layout = gtk_layout_new(NULL, NULL);
vseparator = gtk_separator_menu_item_new();
gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(layout), vseparator, 150, 0);
```

But, I don't understand why it is not being displayed. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separator menu item is not displayed if there are no menu items on either side of it. It doesn't make sense to use a separator menu item outside of a menu anyway.

Use [`GtkVSeparator`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkVSeparator.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks you!I got new fixed to display separator. :-)

Comment: If it solved your problem, then please click the checkmark so that this question doesn't show up as unanswered.